# Compiler Error: Cannot find variable in scope Xcode Bug

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I keep getting a compiler error that's not allowing my app to build.

Below is where I declared the variable showLogOutChoice.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userInfo: UserInfo
    var showLogOutChoice = false
```

I then tried to use the value as a trigger for the actionsheet, and it's the compiler is throwing the error that it's not in scope.

```
.toolbar {
           
            
            ToolbarItem(placement:.navigationBarLeading){
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    VStack{
                    Image("CombIcon")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    Text("Menu")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement:.navigationBarTrailing){
                Button {
                    showLogOutChoice = true
                   
                } label: {
                    Text("Log Out ")
                }
                .confirmationDialog(Text:"Are You Sure You Want To Log Out?", isPresented: $showLogOutChoice , titleVisibility: .visible) {
                    
                    FBAuth.logout(completion: <#T##(Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void#>)
                }
            }
        }
        }
        
    }
```

The variable should still be in scope, and it's not having the same issue when I change the variable to true. So I'm confused. I tried cleaning the build folder and deleting the derived data but still nothing has changed any suggestions.

I'll copy the full file and leave it below as well for reference. PLEASE HELP!

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userInfo: UserInfo
    var showLogOutChoice = false

    //TO DO connect picture to display if picture is not found display person fill
    //TO DO add scroll view

    var body: some View {
        
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
       
        NavigationView{
            
        VStack{

            VStack{
                if (userInfo.user.profilePictureUrl == "")
                {
                Image( systemName: "person.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 120))
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                else{
                WebImage(url: URL(string: userInfo.user.profilePictureUrl))
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                        .clipped()
                        .cornerRadius(120)
                }
            }
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 120)
                        .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
            
            VStack{
        Text("Hello \(userInfo.user.firstName)")
            .font(.custom("coolvetica", size: 55))
            }
           
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
           
            
            VStack(alignment:.leading){
        Text("Your Upcoming Appointment")
            .font(.custom("coolvetica", size: 30))
                
            }
            ZStack{
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13, style: .continuous)
                    .frame(width: screenWidth * 0.9, height: screenHeight * 0.1)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 3, x: 0, y: 6)
                Text("Holy Grail Appointment - Nov. 19th, 2021 8:00 AM")
                    .font(.custom("coolvetica", size: 18))
                
            }.padding(.bottom)
            HStack{
                Button {
                    //TO DO book an appointment action
                } label: {
                    Text("Book An Appointment")
                        .font(.custom("coolvetica", size: 20))
                        .frame(maxWidth: screenWidth * 0.8, minHeight: 20 )
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color("steelteal"))
                        .cornerRadius(42)
                    
                }
                
                
                
//                Button {
//                    //TO DO reschedule an appointment action
//                    // may just make it able to only book an appointment for now
//                } label: {
//                    Text("Reschedule Appointment")
//                        .font(.custom("coolvetica", size: 15))
//                        .padding()
//                        .foregroundColor(.white)
//                        .background(Color("steelteal"))
//                        .cornerRadius(42)
//
//                }

            }
            
            VStack{
                
                Text("My Hair Journey W/ Shei")
                    .font(.custom("coolvetica", size: 30))
            }
            
            HStack{
                
                // need to create logic to save pictures and a note to a specific user
                // create checkin page where pictures can be added the date and a note
                // create display screen that will pop out with full information once photo is click
                // if no checkins/updates are found then display text, no updates found would you like to add one with button
                // allow shei to also add updates to individual users
                
                Image( systemName: "person.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 80))
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                
                Image( systemName: "person.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 80))
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                
                Image( systemName: "person.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 80))
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                
                
            }
            
        }
        }
        .toolbar {
           
            
            ToolbarItem(placement:.navigationBarLeading){
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    VStack{
                    Image("CombIcon")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    Text("Menu")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement:.navigationBarTrailing){
                Button {
                    showLogOutChoice = true
                   
                } label: {
                    Text("Log Out ")
                }
                .confirmationDialog(Text:"Are You Sure You Want To Log Out?", isPresented: $showLogOutChoice , titleVisibility: .visible) {
                    
                    FBAuth.logout(completion: <#T##(Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void#>)
                }
            }
        }
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is way too much unnecessary code to solve this problem. You should go through [Apple's SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) as this is a basic error. At the top, the variable should be `@State var showLogOutChoice = false`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).